# will this INSERT profile work with my Mysql InnoDB oriented DB?

Tags: mysql, innodb, insert-statement

I am wondering on the following subject (regarding INSERT on Mysql - InnoDB tables).

I have a system that does among other system 2 things

1. promote a newsletter to users
2. mass emails to a certain type of users

now, the users will grow to 4k, and supposedly to 40k

When I'm mass emailing, I'm doing an INSERT for each user **id** in a WHILE (which loops through all the users).

I have 2 questions :

1. Is this the best way to do it ?
2. When users reach 40K (40.000 users), will the mysql-server sustain this ?

thanks,

**this is the piece of code i'm using**

```
    $query_write_mass = "SELECT id FROM mya_users ORDER by artist_real_address ASC";
    $result_write_mass = $db->prepare($query_write_mass);
    $result_write_mass->execute();
    while ( list($receiver_id) = $result_write_mass->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH) ) { 

       $stmt = $db->prepare
         ("INSERT INTO inbox(folder_id, sender_id, sender_type, receiver_id, 
           receiver_type, title, message_body, time, date, flag, spam) 
           VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

            $stmt->bindValue(1, 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(2, 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(3, 'x', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(4, $receiver_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(5, $receiver_type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(6, $_POST['title'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(7, $_POST['body'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(8, date("G:i:s"), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(9, date("Y-m-d"), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(10, 'n', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(11, '', PDO::PARAM_STR);                                                                                                                                                                                                   

            $stmt->execute();   
     }
```

This is for the mass emailing for my internal email system.

**UPDATE**

You can find a good answer to this question in my other post (resolved) @

[multiple INSERTS and keeping PDO prepared statement security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170365/multiple-inserts-and-keeping-pdo-prepared-statement-security)

Comment: Consider using a cron job for this to send in batches when your userlist grows so that it becomes manageable and doesnt overwhelm your server :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No. If you can, insert several rows at a time :

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'something'), (2, 'something else')...
```

And if you insert a similar record for all users, an even better approach would be:

```
INSERT INTO t
SELECT 
    "something to insert for all users into t's column 1",
    "something to insert for all users into t's column 2",
    user.field1,
    user.field2
FROM user
-- WHERE some_condition_on_user_table
```

2) Yes, unless you proceed with `while` loops (but even then, it may just work too)

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. Yes, I'm inserting same thing, just the user_id is different, so just one column value will vary. Can you clarify the above "better approach" so it looks more like a real query ? I've never used INSERT into T .. SELECT queries before. Or maybe you have a resource related to the question i can read. Thanks again.

Comment: i'm adding my query + code to my question so you can see how it looks so far

Comment: so basically you say doing 4000 inserts of 10 elements is way much better than doing 40k inserts of 1 element..i think it makes sense

Comment: @AdrianTanase This was the template for an actual query. Check the [full description of this syntax here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html). The `SELECT` part can be a query with arbitrary complexity (you can join tables, etc.). And yes, the basic idea is to insert as many records as possible in one go.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if MySql can handle 40k inserts then, assuming space is available and the machine is reasonable, then this would be no problem.  We have systems inserting hundreds of thousands of rows in a day.

Comment: yes, but this is done one time 40k inserts...(aka when sending mass mail through local mailsystem).....i'm still worried about PDO security, because the solution above should work with escaped values, which is not really why I change all queries to PDO...i mean, no security what so ever...i'll think i'll start a different post about this