# multiple INSERTS and keeping PDO prepared statement security

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have the following piece of code which sends to each member of **mya_users** a mail (this is what INSERT into inbox does.

```
$query_write_mass = "SELECT id FROM mya_users ORDER by artist_real_address ASC";
$result_write_mass = $db->prepare($query_write_mass);
$result_write_mass->execute();
while ( list($receiver_id) = $result_write_mass->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH) ) { 

   $stmt = $db->prepare
     ("INSERT INTO inbox(folder_id, sender_id, sender_type, receiver_id, 
       receiver_type, title, message_body, time, date, flag, spam) 
       VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

        $stmt->bindValue(1, 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(2, 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(3, 'x', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(4, $receiver_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(5, $receiver_type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(6, $_POST['title'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(7, $_POST['body'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(8, date("G:i:s"), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(9, date("Y-m-d"), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(10, 'n', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(11, '', PDO::PARAM_STR);                                                                                                                                                                                                   

        $stmt->execute();   
 }
```

what I want is to keep the benefits of security and escaping of PDO prepared statements,
**BUT** insert say 10 rows at a time, so if I have 40k inserts I would benefit of multiple value insert speed and keep the number of inserts low.

thanks

Comment: I doubt you can have 40k inserts in one query due to max allowed packet. Anyways, did you try *search*?

Comment: there are few things around a solution to my problem on stackoverflow, but none seem to respect PDO security, I thought i'd get a more personalized approach to my problem

Comment: when I say 40k inserts i mean that with the current query, say there are 40kusers => 40k queries...and i want to optimise that

Comment: may be you need to add "prepared statement" term to your search. This is how your security thing is usually called. there are A LOT of questions regarding multiple inserts with PDO prepared statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me assure you that **constant value** is perfectly secure. So, you can dramatically reduce the number of bound parameters in your code

```
INSERT INTO inbox(folder_id, sender_id, sender_type, receiver_id, 
   receiver_type, title, message_body, dt, flag, spam) 
   VALUES (0, 0, 'x', ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), 'n', '')");
```

I also combined two fields `date` and `time` into one `dt`, as there is no reason to have them separated, yet it can let us use shorter code.

And now you can turn to the next step - using [`INSERT .. SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) approach

```
INSERT INTO inbox(folder_id, sender_id, sender_type, receiver_id, 
   receiver_type, title, message_body, dt, flag, spam) 
   SELECT 0, 0, 'x', id, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), 'n', ''
   FROM mya_users ORDER by artist_real_address ASC
```

and bind your data to only three remaining variables!

Comment: yes, but this will do one INSERT @ a time. What I would think would be best is inserting say 10 records with 1 insert, and still respecting PDO syntax.

Comment: i don't understand the INSERT - SELECT statement. It's somehting that I didn't do until now (i have experience in JOINS etc all of that). But I haven't seen a full complete INSERT SELECT with pdo bound data, so I can't grasp it. From what i get, the id and 3 "?" make me wonder what that is all about.

Comment: can you complete your answer so It reflects a full query ? so I can understand it and other who are new to INSERT SELECTs do too ? thanks. will check again in few hours.

Comment: Oh i see, my bad....so it inserts id from my select table, and the remaining 3 values from my binds. My bad, haven't been using insert select statements so far.

Comment: Thanks man, i owe you a good beer, and srry for the trouble with my somewhat silly questions. Now i know INSERT SELECTS ... And i also discovered how i can use sticky caps on me ipad, me hppy, that's where i'm writing from

Comment: I am glad it helped. Sorry, I had no time to explain it deeper but it seems you already figured it out. I'd add a link to that query for the future readers as you suggested.

Comment: i managed to finally implement this INSERT ... FROM SELECT code. it works like a charm, very simple, down-to-the-job. cheers again.